# How are pairs of asymmetric encryption keys generated?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, private-key, key-generator

I have recently been learning about public/private key encryption in my computer science lessons, and how it works in terms of data encryption/decryption. We also covered how it can be used for digital signatures. However, we didn't go into too much detail on how the actual keys are generated themselves.

I know that it begins with a very large number, which is then passed through some kind of keygen algorithm which returns two distinctive keys, one of which is private and the other is public. Are these algorithms known or are they black box systems? And does one user always have the same pair of keys linked to them or do they ever change at any point?

It just seems like a very mathematical issue, as the keys are linked, yet one is not deducible from the other.

[image: asymmetric encryption key generation]

Comment: Kudos for taking the time to make a drawing for your question.

Comment: A general analogy for PK crypto is to think of them as mathematical identities that are computed in at least two steps.  For RSA, one uses an identity with the exponent...the encryption applies one step (exponentiating), and the decryption (also exponentiation) completes the identity to arrive at an exponent equivalent to '1'...returning the message to its original state.  For EC ElGamal, it's the same concept, but using the group-operator on a cyclic group: encryption sends the message some way around the cycle, and decryption pushes it the rest of the way around to complete exactly 1 cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that it begins with a very large number, which is then passed through some kind of keygen algorithm which returns two distinctive keys, one of which is private and the other is public.

Well, that's not entirely correct. Most asymmetric algorithms are of course based on large numbers, but this is not a requirement. There are, for instance, algorithms based on hashing, and hashing is based on bits/bytes, not numbers.

But yes, for asymmetric algorithms usually contain a specific algorithm to perform the key pair generation. For instance, asymmetric encryption consists of a triple `Gen`, `Enc` and `Dec` where `Gen` represents the key pair generation. And the key pair of course consists of a public and a private part.

RSA basically starts off by generating two large random primes, it doesn't start with a single number necessarily.

> Are these algorithms known or are they black box systems?

They are known, and they are fundamental to the security of the system. You cannot use just any numbers to perform, e.g., RSA. Note that for RSA there are different algorithms and configurations possible; not every system will use the same `Gen`.

> And does one user always have the same pair of keys linked to them or do they ever change at any point?

That depends on the key management of the system. Usually there is some way of refreshing or regenerating keys. For instance X.509 certificates tend to have a end date (the date of expiry or expiration date), so you cannot even keep using the corresponding private key forever; you have to refresh the certificates and keys now and then.

> It just seems like a very mathematical issue, as the keys are linked, yet one is not deducible from the other.

That's generally not correct. The public key is usually easy to derive from the private key. For RSA the public exponent may not be known, but it is usually set to a fixed number (65537). This together with the modulus - also part of the private key - makes the public key. For Elliptic Curve keys a private random value is first produced and the public key is directly derived from it.

You can of course never derive the private key from the public key; that would make no sense - it would not be very private if you could.

Answer (score 1):

In [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) the generated two numbers `p` and `q` are very large prime numbers more or less the same size, which are used to calculate `N` which derives the public/private keys using [modulo arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation).

The following [answer in crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/79) describes in more details how we can start from a random (large) number and use [Fermat test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) and [Miller-Rabin tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) to reach a number that is very probable to be prime.

Comment: This answer is specific to RSA, might be worth noting that in your answer.

Comment: @LukePark I'm not familiar with any other encryption algorithm that uses public/private key-pairs which might create ambiguity.

Comment: ElGamal?  DSA?  Strictly speaking, DH has public and private keys too.  There are countless algorithms that are considered public and private key algorithms.  You should state in your answer that you are specifically talking about RSA, since the OP was asking about PKC in general.